# Sorting txt data files while importing in Excel Data Query

Tags: excel, sorting

I am trying to enter approximately 190 txt datafiles in Excel using the New Query tool (Data->New Query->From File->From Folder). In the Windows explorer the data are properly ordered: the first being 0summary, the second 30summary etc.

However, when entering them through the query tool the files are sorted as shown in the picture (see line 9 for example, you will see that the file is not in the right position):

[image]

The files are sorted based on the first digit instead of the value represented. Is there a solution to this issue? I have tried putting space between the number and the summary but it also didn't work. I saw online that Excel doesn't recognize the text within "" or after /, but I am not allowed to save the text files with those symbols in their name in Windows. Even when removed the word summary the problem didn't fix. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your names include the word Summary:

You can add a column "Extract" / "Text before delimiter" enter "Summary", change the column type to Number and sort over that column

[image]

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the only numbers are those you wish to sort on, you can

- add a custom column with just the numbers
- Change the data type to `whole number`
- sort on that.

The formula for the custom column:

```
 Text.Select([Name],{"0".."9"})
```

*If the alpha portion varies, and you need to sort on that also, you can do something similar adding another column for the alpha portion, and sorting on that.*

If there might be digits after the leading digits upon which you want to sort, then use the following formula for the added column which will extract only the digits at the beginning of the file name:

```
=Text.Middle([Name],0,Text.PositionOfAny([Name],{"A".."z"}))
```